# Непонятные отступы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток. Примерно месяц назад начал изучать верстку сайтов, недавно скачал готовый сайт, чтобы попробовать разобраться в коде и наткнулся на такую проблему: когда я просто начал делать код более читабельным (ставить табы и энтеры) сайт начал "ехать", т. е. кое-где начали ставиться отступы непонятно откуда, кое-где просто переходы на новую строку. Так же пробовал прогонять его через различные сервисы, которые делают код более читабельным (HTML Beautifier) и та же проблема. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: отступы (пробелы, табы, переносы строки, ...) в разметке воспринимаются как пробелы при рендере ... ну как-то так .... а вообще, вопрос конечно ни о чем.

Comment: Даже если они за тегами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример лучше слов

```html
<p>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
</p>

<p>
    <button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button>
</p>
```

Что бы избавиться от такого можно использовать комментирование

```html
<p>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
</p>

<p>
    <button>1</button><!--
    --><button>2</button><!--
    --><button>3</button>
</p>
```

Или задать `font-size: 0`

```html
<p>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
</p>

<p style="font-size:0">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
</p>
```

С тонкостями и то, какие элементы подвержены такому ознакомитесь с опытом.

Главное, что будете иметь ввиду.